# On all Android devices,when I press the home button

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

In my program's any activity ,I press the home button,and then in desktop press my app's icon,I saw the launch activity,not before activity.What happen on my app?
And I found if I use Android Studio run without sign,the app is run normally.A month ago,I move the codes from eclipse to AS,on eclipse IDE not found this problem.Can anybody help me? Very thx.
Maybe grammar errors,sorry.

EDIT:I found this is an Android bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658

And the solution is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658#c14

Comment: paste some sources such as `android manifest` or `acitivity xml` etc.

Comment: plz try to write proper grammar.

Comment: uh, I'm not familiar with English grammar,I just use Google translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on real device, make sure you didn't set the flag
     `Don't keep activities`  in `Developer options`.

On emulator check in running configurations that you launch the default activity.
On manifest check **that you do not** **exclude your activities from recent**.

Comment: I am not set the Developer options.

Comment: then provide your manifest codes so it will be more clear where is your problem